# i am very new to flask and i am trying to write a test program that displays numbers in the range of 1 to the given number

Tags: python, html, flask

But after execution the only output i get is '1'. i guess this is because i have not made the code dynamic??
here is the html:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/disp" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Number:</p>
         <p><input type = "number" name = "nm" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

this is the flask:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect, url_for, request
import test
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/disp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def printing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        val = request.form['nm']
        return test.pri(int(val))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is the python program:

```
import time
def pri(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        return str(i)
```

sorry for asking a noob question

Comment: inside the for loop you use return that is why you are getting "1" only

Comment: you may be interested in the templates feature as you build from here

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  If you're trying to work out what is going wrong in a simple test program, this post has some pointers about how to go about debugging it: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in pri(n) function. Within first iteration of 'for' function program hits return and ends.
If you want response like "123456..." you can replace it with:

```
import time
def pri(n):
    tmp = ""
    for i in range(1,n):
        tmp += str(i) 
    return tmp
```

Comment: yeah this could work. but my final goal is to use this to display temperature readings from a pi board which gets updated every 2 seconds. Is there any easy way to do that? I've come across some solutions that use web sockets and stuff, but unfortunately i am not that well versed with that.

Comment: Websocket is the best solution because you can constantly send data from server to client without request. It can be easily set up with socketio library and flask-socketio.
If you don't want to use it, I think the simpliest solution will be setting your website to refresh every 2 second and returning new temperature value on server side.